# Are there area-wide ski passes in southern Poland?

Tags: poland, skiing

I may have the opportunity to visit the Polish mountains next February but when glancing through offers it looks like ski slopes are "disconnected" - each of them is one single entity.

I am used the French system where you have a whole mountain (or two or three) covered with ski paths which are available with a single pass (and interconnected, you ski from one to another).

Is there such a system in Poland? (specifically in Bukowina Tatrzanska which seems to be a ski resort)

Answer (score 2):

From a quick look at [this site](https://www.skiresort.info/ski-resorts/poland/) most of the Polish resorts seem rather small compared to anything in the Alps. Białka Tatrzańska has a 230 m vertical extent and 18.3 km of pistes. For reference, somewhere like La Plagne has a 1960 m vertical extent and 225 km of pistes. Sure, the lift tickets are cheaper and skiing might not be your only reason for visiting the area, but if you're used to the French multi-mountain resorts you might need to ensure that you have appropriate expectations. The lifts in B.T. do not seem to be connected at all to those in other nearby places, so I suspect that's why they don't appear to offer a combined ticket.